# querying database with array variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im working on a page for a sports team where the coach can select his team. What im trying to do is:

1) Print different positions

2) Assign next to position name, players who are ONLY relevant to the
    position. (**i.e if the positions name is flanker only flankers should
    be displayed in the drop-down menu**)

My logic for the above problem is:

- Assign position names to array called $position Loop over array
- querying database, with position having a different value after each loop.
- Selected players that match the position gets assigned to an
        array called $playerName
- Print the $position variable
- Create dropdown menu for each position
- assign value
        from $playername array to the option element in the drop down
        menu.
- Now there should be different positions with dropdown menus,
        next to them, containing player names relevant to position.

> //create position array

```
$position = array(
    "THP",
    "HKR",
    "LH",
    "LK4",
    "LK5",
    "FLH"
);
echo '<form name="slectPlayers" method="post">';
foreach ($position as $pposition) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `player_id`,`name`,`surname` FROM `player_info` WHERE `position` = '$pposition'") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //create arrays
        $id[]             = $row['player_id'];
        $playerName[]     = $row['name'];
        $playerLastName[] = $row['surname'];
        // print position and open select element
        foreach ($position as $playerPosition) {
            print $playerPosition;
            echo '<select>';
            foreach ($playerName as $name) { //assign playername to position element
                echo '<option>' . $name;
                '</option>';
                echo '</select>';
                echo '<br />';
            } //close assign player nae to position loop
        } //end print position and open select loop
    } //end while  loop
} //end opening for each loop
echo '</form>';
```

unfortunately for me either my logic is wrong or my code is incorrect. This is the ouput I get:  **(Note only the name Tendai is displayed in all dropdown meus no other names appear)** 
[image]

If been struggling with this one all morning if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated

(note to modirators the picure above does not contain real names and is only a fictional database)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. the logic is something different

```
function get_players_by_position($position)
{
    $query  =   "SELECT
                  `player_id`,
                  `name`,
                  `surname`
                FROM `player_info`
                WHERE `position` = $position
                ORDER BY name   ";

    $result =   mysql_query($query);
    $data   =   array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $data[] =   $row;
    }

    return $data;
}   

foreach($position as $pposition){
    $data   =   get_players_by_position($pposition);
    echo $pposition;    
    echo '<select>';
    foreach($data as $row){
        echo '<option '.$row['id'].'>' . $row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<br />';
    unset($data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I use the $position variable in two loops because I need its value twice...does that make sense? or is it wrong of me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, you could remove the two `foreach` loops in the `while` loop. Use `$pposition` in place of `$playerPosition` and your code should work as expected. Here's your code, with my suggested changes, in your procedural style:

```
$position = array(
    "THP",
    "HKR",
    "LH",
    "LK4",
    "LK5",
    "FLH"
 );
 echo '<form name="selectPlayers" method="post">';
 foreach ($position as $pposition) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `player_id`,`name`,`surname` FROM `player_info` 
                         WHERE `position` = '$pposition'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<select name="'. $pposition . '">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        print $pposition;

        echo '<option value="' . $row['player_id'] . '">'.
                 $row['name'] .' '. $row['surname'].
             '</option>';

    } //end while  loop
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<br />';
} //end opening for each loop
echo '</form>';
```